# Why is the column name written in the cell of the report table?

Tags: c#, rdlc

i making report using rdlc and i chose columns one by one from the cells of the table. , but column name is printed top of contents in cells

how can i hide or does not showing column name in cells??

i attach my report image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9D06.jpg)

and my code below

```
 LocalReport report12 = new LocalReport()
  string path = Application.StartupPath + @"\_Report\Report1.rdlc";
 // MessageBox.Show(path);
                report12.ReportPath = path;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    dt.Columns.Add("partno" , System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
                    dt.Columns.Add("partname", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
                    dt.Columns.Add("drawno", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
                    dt.Columns.Add("lot", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
                    dt.Columns.Add("packingno", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
                //dt.Columns.Add("partno", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));

                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                    dr["partno"] = "AAAA1";
                    dr["partname"] = "(38.45T)";
                    dr["drawno"] = "CE630FMCDA08";
                    dr["lot"] = "2021-04-19";
                    dr["packingno"] = "61";

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                   
                    report12.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1" , dt));

                try { 
                PrintToPrinter(report12);

                }
                catch (Exception eex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(eex.Message);
                }
```

thanks!

Comment: from what I see in the image, try garbing first row(the column headers row) after this row 
` dt.Rows.Add(dr)` and search for some hide property, something like this `dt.Rows[0].hide = true`